# Filter Column using where condtion in column level in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I want to apply a column level filter like if there is an account of 30 then that value has to be taken. But I do not want it to apply this account filter to the whole table as I have few more columns with the same ask like this.

I want to filter it in the select statement column level not after the from table. Value in the select statement is the required column that is needed with filters on account and month columns.

For Ex. (Select value where account =30 and month = 'jan' as new_value from table)

I do not want (select value from table where account = 30 and month = 'jan')

Please let me know can this be done using any functions in Snowflake?

Comment: what do you want selected if the account is <> 30?

Comment: how many values aha account 30 provide data please

Answer (score 0):

Typically this would be done as a CASE statement.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN t.account = 30 and t.month = 'Jan' THEN t.value
        WHEN t.account = 30 and t.month = 'Feb' THEN t.othervalue
        ...
        ELSE t.somedefaultvalue --or NULL or whatever
    END as value
FROM
    table t
```

CASE is like a If/then/else statement in other languages.

Comment: What if I have two filters needed.. like account = 30 and month = jan??

Comment: I get all Nulls when I do this

Comment: @Anonymous then the values are not matching correctly.  Please add a sample of your table data to the question so we can see what we're dealing with